# ios - Check If File Has Loaded

Tags: ios, xcode, callback, loading

Is there a way to check whether a file from the main bundle or documents directory on the iphone/ipad has been loaded successfully. I want a callback to do some extra things only on load, otherwise they do not execute because they are ahead of the file.

Thanks,
Ashley

EDIT: To avoid confusion, I actually need to run another method or just set some properties as soon as the file has loaded. Is there a completion block for this?

Comment: it will be mostly images, but there could be a couple of txt files in there too.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSFileManager *manager = [[NSFileManager alloc]init];

NSString *filePath = [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Your File Name" ofType:@"YOur FIleTYPE"];

if([ manager fileExistsatPath: filePath])
{
NSLog(@"exist and loaded");
}
[manager release];
```

This is one way i think will work..there might be some error in the above code..i recommend autocomplete feature of Xcode

Comment: i think you missed the point of the question. I don't want to check if the file exists, but when the file has loaded.